# HTML To Add 1/2 inch Pad To Right And Left Margin of Table

Tags: html, html-table

I am generating an HTML table and I need to add a 1/2 inch padding to both the left and the right margin.  I have seen numerous ways to do such with CSS but how is this done with straight HTML?  I have also seen how to set such with pixels by using

```
<table id="margin" width="100%" style="margin-right:10px" style="margin-left:10px">
```

however, how does this translate to inches?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length there is info about inches. If this is print css then just use `margin: 0 10in;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
<table id="margin" width="100%" style="margin-right:10px;margin-left:10px">
```

demo:

```css
div{background:wheat}
table{background:green;}
```

```html
<div>
  <table style="margin-left:100px;margin-right:100px">
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>Test 1</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Test 2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Test 3</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Note that you can also combine the two settings like this:

```
style="margin:0 10px"
```

This says, margin top/bottom = 0 and margin left/right = 10px

Comment: Can you put some info on `however, howd this translate to inches?`

Comment: Does 10px = 1/2 inch?

Comment: No, 10px is very small - I just used the value that you used and corrected your syntax. I imagine you can figure out the best value. However, I would use vh or vw instead of px, if you want the value to be consistent on different sized monitors/devices. eg. `margin: 0 4vh`

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
style="padding:0px 10px;"
```

Comment: that's the way to go!